# Change computer identity while logged in via RDP

Tags: domain, windows-sbs-2011

If I'm logged in to an SBS 2011 server through RDP and I go into System settings and change the computer identity (machine name and domain) - will I be locked out, as the admin user I'm logged in as was created while the domain was called something else?

Comment: Are you trying to rename the SBS server?! .. Avoid very bad idea!!

Comment: I never tried with SBS 2011 but with Windows, I've done it many times. The change only takes place after reboot. So you will get told to reboot the server, reboot it and then it will have a new name.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that you'll be locked out, but that doesn't mean I'd recommend it.  Exchange and the other services on your SBS box will likely have an epic fit if you rename them.

Renaming an Exchange server is not supported, according to [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/d50b9b6c-6280-479b-a4ec-be5fe4b034a4/changing-exchange-server-name?forum=exchange2010).

As for renaming the domain, it's not supported with Exchange 2007 and 2010 (SBS 2011 comes with Exchange 2010).  Quoting the [Introduction to Administering Active Directory Domain Rename](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816848%28WS.10%29.aspx):

> The domain rename operation is not supported in Microsoft Exchange
>   Server 2007 or Exchange Server 2010. DNS domain rename is supported in
>   Exchange Server 2003. However, renaming of the NetBIOS domain name is
>   not supported in any version of Exchange Server. Other non-Microsoft
>   applications might also not support domain rename. For more
>   information about other Microsoft applications that are incompatible
>   with domain rename, see article 300684
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=185229) in the Microsoft
>   Knowledge Base.

In short:  I'm almost certain that your login will work but that Exchange and Sharepoint won't.

Sorry.